# delete everyting above the pattern

Tags: unix, sed, awk, html-table

My question is to decide out of three patterns which will occur first and delete everything before the first pattern and similarly delete everything after last pattern.

I am aware that to delete everthing above pattern below command could be used:

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p' input
```

`grep -E -m1 "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3"`  will print the line consisting the first pattern, I think I have to feed output of this command to some variant of `sed` but not sure how to do so.

1. PATTERN1
2. PATTERN2
3. PATTERN3

Line1 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line2 only meant for giving an example PATTERN2 to make my query clear to all
Line3 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line4 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line5 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line6 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line7 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line8 only meant for giving an example pattern2 to make my query clear to all
Line9 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line10 only meant for giving an example pattern3 to make my query clear to all
Line11  only meant for giving an example PATTERN2 to make my query clear to all
Line12 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line13 only meant for giving an example pattern3 to make my query clear to all
Line14 only meant for giving an example  to make my query clear to all

**Desired output:**

If the first pattern is PATTERN2 and pattern3 is the last pattern among the three then below would be desired output:

Line2 only meant for giving an example PATTERN2 to make my query clear to all
Line3 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line4 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line5 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line6 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line7 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line8 only meant for giving an example pattern2 to make my query clear to all
Line9 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line10 only meant for giving an example pattern3 to make my query clear to all
Line11  only meant for giving an example PATTERN2 to make my query clear to all
Line12 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line13 only meant for giving an example pattern3 to make my query clear to all

Comment: Are patterns string or regular expressions? Can one pattern be contained in another pattern? Does a pattern need to be a whole word? Does the pattern matching have to be case-sensitive or case-insensitive (as your example seems to show)?

Comment: your below solution is working flawlessly in my script. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else, just use awk. You didn't provide any sample input or expected output or any information about what you mean by "pattern"s so this is an untested guess but maybe it will work for you:

```
awk -v pats='pattern1|pattern2|pattern3' '
    { data[NR] = $0 }
    $0 ~ pats { if (start) end=NR; else start=NR }
    END{ for (i=start; i<=end; i++) print data[i] }
' file
```

Commented version:

```
awk -v pats='pattern1|pattern2|pattern3' # or-separated list of patterns to be matched                            
    { data[NR] = $0 }                    # save current line in an array indexed by line number
    $0 ~ pats {                          # IF the current line matches any of the target patterns THEN
        if (start)                       #    IF the start line number is already recorded THEN
            end=NR;                      #        remember the current line number as the last one on which one of the patterns exists
        else                             #    ELSE
            start=NR                     #        remember the current line number as the first one on which one of the patterns exists
                                         #    ENDIF
    }                                    # ENDIF
    END{                                 # Once all of the file has been read into the array
        for (i=start; i<=end; i++)       # Loop through the array, starting at the first line on which one of the patterns was found
                                         # and ending on the last line on which one of the patterns was found
            print data[i]                #     Print the contents of the array at each line number in the loop.
    }
' file
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me,can you explain bit about above awk command ?

Comment: I added a commented version.

Answer (score 1):

As you've shown, this will remove anything before the first occurrance:

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p' file
```

So we can take the output of that, reverse it and apply the 
program again. Then reverse the output of *that* and we have all the text between the first and last matches:

```
seq 10 | sed -n '/4\|7/,$p' | tac | sed -n '/4\|7/,$p' | tac
```

```
4
5
6
7
```

And we can put that into a function:

```
after() { sed -n '/'"$1"'/,$p'; }
between() { after "$1" | tac | after "$1" | tac; }
seq 10 | after '4\|7'
echo ===
seq 10 | between '4\|7'
```

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
===
4
5
6
7
```